# Heroku Build Error: Unable to load xmlsec-openssl library

Tags: python, django, heroku, xmlsec, django-saml2-auth

I was in the process of trying to update my team's app from heroku-18 stack to heroku-22. Due to the Python version that supports heroku-22, I had to update to Python 3.9.16 too and as well as one of the Python build-packs for Django SAML2 Authentication. Going from this buildpack:[django-saml2-auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-saml2-auth/) to [grafana-django-saml2-auth](https://pypi.org/project/grafana-django-saml2-auth/) however one of the installations needed (xmlsec1) is resulting in the website saying Sorry, you are not allowed to access this app and this error. Any ideas of how to fix it?

> Error: unable to load xmlsec-openssl library. Make sure that you have
> this it installed, check shared libraries path (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
> envornment variable or use "--crypto" option to specify different
> crypto engine.
> Error: initialization failed
> func=xmlSecCryptoShutdown:file=app.c:line=69:obj=unknown:subj=cryptoShutdown:error=9:feature is not implemented:
> func=xmlSecAppCryptoShutdown:file=crypto.c:line=48:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecCryptoShutdown:error=1:xmlsec library function failed:
> Error: xmlsec crypto shutdown failed.
> output=Usage: xmlsec  [] []
> xmlsec is a command line tool for signing, verifying, encrypting and
> decrypting XML documents. The allowed  values are:
>   --help        display this help information and exit
>   --help-all    display help information for all commands/options and exit
>   --help-  display help information for command  and exit
>   --version     print version information and exit
>   --keys        keys XML file manipulation
>   --sign        sign data and output XML document
>   --verify      verify signed document
>   --sign-tmpl   create and sign dynamicaly generated signature template
>   --encrypt     encrypt data and output XML document
>   --decrypt     decrypt data from XML document

I've tried changing the Metadata and updating the packages